# C++: Way around dependent templates

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a class template like this:

```cpp
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    class ClassName {
        // Members variables and Functions based on the template parameter types
    };
```

`(T1, T2)` can either be `(class A, class B)` or `(class C, class D)` only.
So, T1 alone is enough to determine T2.
Is there any way to only take T1 as a parameter and write the same class? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you have `T3` at all, if it's always going to be `T1`?

Comment: If only there was a tool to use when you can `enum`erate all possible options...

Comment: It's not clear what one would "rewrite", since there's nothing in this class. Since `T3` is just `T1`, and `T2` is just flipping the value of `T1`, are you asking how to write a type that is the flipped type of another type?

Comment: @ChrisMM I have to decide T3 based on T1 but only take T1 as a parameter. Perhaps, my int and float example causing the confusion.

Comment: If the example does not illustrate the intent, perhaps add a better example? :)

Comment: Its cool to do in practice I guess.. I just don't see a practical use for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your template only depends on a single parameter, you should not declare it with 2 parameters. You can use `std::conditional` together with `std::is_same` to declare conditional aliases.

If you want:

> (T1, T2) can either be (class A, class B) or (class C, class D) only

If "only" is meant as: User only ever instantiates for `A` or `C` and in that case `T2` should be `B` / `D`:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct D {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  using T1 = T;
  using T2 = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<A, T>, B, D>;
};
```

`Foo<A>::T2` is `B` and `Foo<C>::T2` is `D`. Actually `Foo<T>::T2` is `D` for any `T` that is not `A`. In other words, as mentioned above, the premise is that it is only instantiated for either `A` or `C`. If the template itself should make sure that only instantiations for `A` or `C` are valid, you might want to add a `static_assert` (again using `std::is_same` to check that `T` is among the allowed types).

Comment: I think `using T3 = T` would be valid too, little simpler.

Comment: I would actively recommend _against_ SFINAE here, since that results in hard to diagnose compiler errors. Prefer instead `static_assert`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think this was the solution I was looking for. Thanks.
On a side note, is there any duplicate of this? If not, please let me know any changes to the question (for better reference)

Answer (score 4):

Make an enumeration of your configurations:

```
enum class ClassConfigEnum { AB, CD};
template<ClassConfigEnum config> struct ClassConfig;
template<> struct ClassConfig<AB> {
    using T1 = A;
    using T2 = B;
};
template<> struct ClassConfig<CD> {
    using T1 = C;
    using T2 = D;
};
```

And then have the class use the enumerated configuration

```
template <ClassConfigEnum config>
class ClassName {
    using T1 = ClassConfig<config>::typename T1;
    using T2 = ClassConfig<config>::typename T2;
};
```

Comment: Amazing solution for generic situations. I have been looking into such methods. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can write a type trait:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};

template <typename Type> struct Dependent {};

template<>
struct Dependent<A> {
    using type = B;
};

template<>
struct Dependent<C> {
    using type = D;
};


template <typename Type>
class ClassName {
    using Dependent = typename Dependent<Type>::type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<Dependent<A>::type, B>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<Dependent<C>::type, D>::value, "");
    // Dependent<B>::type a;    error: 'type' is not a member of 'Dependent<B>'  
}
```